# « (Y) en avoir dedans » : qu'y a-t-il dedans au juste et d'où cela vient-il ?

Tags: sens, expressions, pronoms, québec, origine-ou-raison

> 4° Y en avoir dedans = être très vigoureux, très habile, très
>   spirituel. Ex.: Il n'est pas gros mais il *y en a dedans* = il est
>   très vigoureux. 
>  Can. — *En avoir dans le corps* = m.s.
>
> [ [*Glossaire du parler canadien français*](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf), éd. L'action sociale,
>   1930, à la p. 264 « dedans ». ]

Je comprends le sens de *vigoureux* mais surtout l'idée de [*dynamisme ou d'énergie*](http://www.legrenierdebibiane.com/participez/Expressions/quebec.html) (et d'ailleurs c'est à la vue de Président de la République française que j'ai pensé à ça) sauf qu'on trouve très peu d'informations là-dessus. Au [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/dedans/22529/locution) on a *avoir le vent dedans* mais c'est littéralement le (la voile du) bateau, non sans évoquer ce qui m'est plus familier tel qu'*avoir le vent dans les [voiles](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/voiles/1)* (bien réussir). On peut « avoir » bien des choses différentes, dans le sens d'une caractéristique ou d'un état de fait, comme [*avoir du chien*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir_du_chien), [*de la gueule*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir_de_la_gueule), [*de l'allure*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir_de_l%E2%80%99allure) etc ; à ne pas confondre avec l'[excès](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/plein_de_marde) de ces dernières choses. Enfin, à ma connaissance on dit *en avoir dedans* et non *y en avoir dedans* (d'une chose j'entendrais de cela *il en reste* ou *il y en a déjà*), et c'est simplement le pronom masculin *il* ou le féminin *elle*, qu'[on prononce](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Troisi.C3.A8me_personne_du_singulier_.C2.AB_il_.C2.BB) souvent [i] et [a] ou [al], respectivement, au Québec (aussi [ailleurs](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/y/2) de manière populaire, à certains égards) :

> Lui, i(l) en a dedans.
>   Elle, e(lle) en a dedans.

---

- L'expression *(y) en avoir dedans* a-t-elle un sens figé ou est-elle toujours reliée à un antécédent dont on pourrait dire qu'il est référencé par le pronom *en*, et donc analysable, ou les deux sont-ils possibles ; quel est le sens généralement attesté de cette expression au Québec et la (re)connaît-on ailleurs ; n'est-ce qu'un principe actif protéiforme que cette chose qu'on a ?
- Aujourd'hui, l'expression se construit-elle avec ou sans le pronom [*y*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/y/1) au Québec ; quel en est ou en aurait été le rôle ou la fonction ; une idée de destination est-elle requise ou est-ce le tour et les autres éléments de la phrase qui commandent sa présence (la coordination *mais* dans l'exemple au *Glossaire* par opposition à la répétition du pronom *lui/il* dans le mien) ?
- A-t-on une idée de l'origine ou de la raison de l'expression ; s'agissait-il d'une référence à la voile, au poêle à bois ou au moteur, d'une simplification/ellipse d'une expression comme *avoir de la gueule* ; a-t-on d'autres précisions concernant l'évolution de l'expression et de son sens, le cas échéant ?

Answer (score 4):

L'expression "en avoir dedans" est vraiment lié au fait d'avoir de l'énergie, de la volonté, du courage, ce qui permet d'aller un peu plus loin que la normal. L'expression peu être utilisé correctement de cette façon:

> Regarde ce que Marc a réussi, ce gars, il en a dedans.
>
> Joannie a eu le courage de faire ça, elle en a dedans.

L'expression avec un "Y" a la même signification, seulement, elle vient du [joual](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joual), généralement, on le prononce de cette façon:

> T'as tu vu ça, y'en a d'dans le p'tit gars.
>
> Eille, a n'a d'dans c'te fille là.

La signification est la même mais les pronons "il" et "elle" sont remplacés par "y" et "a". On peut aussi utiliser l'expression au pluriel:

> Y'en ont d'dans eux-autres.

Pour ce qui est des origines de l'expression par contre, je n'en ai aucune idée. Je ne serais pas surpris que ce soit comme tu proposes, en rapport avec un poêle à bois, dans ce temps là, c'était la principale source d'énergie.

Comment: Merci ! Est-ce que ça marcherait pour l'habileté, l'intellect ou la spiritualité ? Si je parle de quelqu'un assis sur une chaise immobile qui lit un journal et je dis que lui y en a dedans, serait-ce ironique ou autrement vous comprendriez quoi de ça, ce serait vague, je réfère à une expérience antérieure où j'ai été témoin de son comportement, ou par défaut c'est soit l'énergie, la volonté ou le courage et lequel précisément selon vous ? La plupart de vos exemples introduisent l'antécédent avec le contexte (n.b. vous avez oublié _dit/fait_ pr. Marc), sauf le dernier.

Comment: Oui, c'est également utilisé pour ce qui est de l'habileté et de l'intellect, pour ce qui est de la spiritualité, j'imagine que ce serait possible quoi que je ne l'ai j'avais entendu dans ce sens. Je dirais que de dire ça d'une personne qui est passive en ce moment serait effectivement ironique ou même sarcastique (en tout cas, si moi je le disais).

Answer (score 3):

Je suis un locuteur francophone natif de Belgique, et je ne connais pas cette expression, elle me paraît effectivement propre au Québec. Par contre, en français de France et Belgique, on utilise familièrement l'expression "il y en a là-dedans", mais qui signifie "je suis/tu es/il/elle est intelligent(e)" (l'expression s'accompagne d'ailleurs souvent d'un geste de l'index sur le crâne).

Comment: Merci! C'est donc la matière grise ? Quelle serait une prononciation très populaire de « il y en a là-dedans » en français de France et Belgique ?

Comment: -1 car cette réponse ne répond à aucune des questions originales, l'auteur de la réponse admet ne pas connaître l'expression et l'explication donnée pour l'expression est en lien avec un sens qui n'est pas celui d'intérêt ici. Dans l'expression "il y en a là-dedans" on ne parle pas de matière grise, mais plutôt de vigueur ou d'énergie.

Comment: Je ne prétendais pas répondre à l'ensemble des questions mais uniquement à celle qui demandait si "en avoir dedans" était (re) connu hors du Québec, et ajoutais qu'elle ressemblait par contre à une autre expression courante. Agent Baptiste: "il y en a là-dedans" (qui, on on bien d'accord, n'est pas "en avoir dedans") se prononce souvent "y en a là-d'dans".

Answer (score 1):

Telle que je la comprends, cette expression est couramment utilisée pour se vanter (sur un ton humoristique). Elle signifie "être intelligent", on la dit généralement en montrant ou en tapotant son crâne du doigt (sous-entendu *il y en a dans ma tête / dans mon cerveau*) :

[image]

> T'as vu, y'en a là-d'dans, pas vrai ?

Comment: Merci ! Ce qu'il y a dans la tête, ce serait la matière grise selon vous ? Quand vous dites couramment dans ce sens, vous entendez au Québec si je comprends bien ?

Comment: Cette réponse est incorrecte et ne répond pas à la question originale. L'auteur de la réponse n'est pas Québécois (selon son profile) et semble donc répondre pour une réalité Française ou Suisse qui n'est pas celle du Québec.

Comment: @ApplePie Je n'ai jamais prétendu être québecois, mais la question comportait notamment *quel est le sens généralement attesté de cette expression au Québec ***et la (re)connaît-on ailleurs ?***.